# How to keep two input box side by side in html using CSS?

Tags: html, css

Hi I am new in Html & Css. I want to keep two input box side by side. Just like below picture

[image: my expected html look]

But unable to so, and don't have no idea how to achive this.

so far my code is

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="myCss.css">
<head>
<body>

<div>
  <div id="leftDiv">
    <input type="text" name="firstName" value=""/>
  </div>
  <div id="rightDiv">
    <input type="text" name="lastName" value=""/>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and css

```
body {
  background-color:#CCFFCC;
}

#leftDiv{
  float:left;
  padding:38px;
  margin-left: 370px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}

#rightDiv{
  float:right;
  padding:38px;
  margin-right: 482px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
```

Please help me. Also if someone can provide me some book or tutorial reference where I can get some **practical examples** that will be great. I tried to find books or tutorials with practical example which can be used in actual application but did not find any. Please suggest me. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I deleted my answer, but that was odd. The design view on Visual Studio was not showing me what the browsers were. Sorry about the false advice.

Comment: It is ok, but thanks to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to get rid of those extra margins,
then, we give a name to our parent div,
set a with (big enough for both #leftDiv & #rightDiv),
then only by floating them, you can get what you are looking for:

```css
body {
  background-color:#CCFFCC;
}
#parentDiv{
width:263px;
  margin:auto;
}
#leftDiv{
  float:left;
}

#rightDiv{
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="myCss.css">
<head>
<body>

<div id="parentDiv">
  <div id="leftDiv">
    <input type="text" name="firstName" value=""/>
  </div>
  <div id="rightDiv">
    <input type="text" name="lastName" value=""/>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, but still I am not getting what I am looking for.

Comment: would you please explain? Press "Run Snippet" and it looks like your image

Comment: gaps between two input boxes should be very less.

Comment: You can adjust it by decreasing #parentDiv's width!

Comment: but I don't want to use java script.

Comment: It has nothing to do with JS, in the code above, when you set parent's width to a lower number inputs get closer to each other, I've edited the code, check it out!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89101/discussion-between-rajorshi-roy-and-ramtin-gh).

Answer (score 0):

Use this css and you will accomplish what you need very easy without margins or floats

Check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/w95yseee/

```
body {
  background-color:#CCFFCC;
}
body > div{
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}

#leftDiv{
  padding:38px;
  padding-right: 0px;
    display:table-cell;
  margin-right: 0px;
}

#rightDiv{
  padding:38px;
  padding-left: 0px;
    display:table-cell;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
```

Comment: gaps between two input boxes still present.

Comment: yes it is working. Please also explain it. and please also suggest some good books with practical examples.

Comment: by the way why we need java script? I don't want that.

Comment: oh no, you can delete that, I forgot to delete by myself, anyway in the javascript tab is css too, you can delete it.

Comment: https://www.codecademy.com/ , http://www.w3schools.com/css/ and a lot of practice. You shouldn't read books, you should try and try again because in this way you will learn